# Ubuntu 16.04 and 17.10 do not perform well for me. What should I install instead?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, distro-recommendation

In another question of mine, I reported that Ubuntu wasn't working well, and the only answer I got said that Ubuntu 17.10 has bad memory usage, and recommended I move from Ubuntu to Xubuntu, Lubuntu, etc.

My question is, should I move to a different Linux system (I want a faster yet beautiful one) or move to a older Ubuntu version? I have tried 16.04 (with unity) and now I have the 17.10, both of them give me problems.

Once again, my specs are:

- 2 GB of RAM
- Intel Core 2 Duo CPU T6570 2.10GHz x 2
- 64 bits
- 500 GB of Memory
- My graphics card is NVIDIA GeForce 9300M GS - 256 MB, Núcleo: 580 MHz, Memoría: 702 MHz, GDDR3 VRAM, 7.15.11.7482 (ForceWare 174.82), it seems that Ubuntu doesn't recognize it, what Linux distro will?

Comment: Wait a month and then try Ubuntu MATE 18.04 32-bit which is a long term supported release, support for five years.

Comment: It is a good idea to try Lubuntu with an ultra-light desktop environment and Ubuntu Budgie, Ubuntu MATE, Xubuntu with medium light desktop environments. Try them live and select the flavour that works well and you like best. See [Try Ubuntu (Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, ...) before installing it](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389).

Comment: You don't say what "wasn't working well". But... you have barely enough RAM to effectively run Ubuntu. Add RAM. Or try a lightweight version of Ubuntu live Lubuntu or Xubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Wait to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and try "Minimal Installation" if you don't like it try other Linux distros.

I try diferents versions using VirtualBox, but by the moment Ubuntu is the best for me.